# Weird onClick behavior on an element generated by ZF Helper

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using [FormImage Helper](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Helper/FormImage.php) from Zend Framework 1 in a project. The output generated by the helper (on lines [84-91](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Helper/FormImage.php#L84-L91)) is as follow:

```
<input type="image" name="form_image" id="form_image" src="/images/icons/16x16/user1_add.png">
```

On the application I am getting a weird behavior where I click on such "image" and I got redirected to a URL. Why? I don't think there is a event handler for the class or the name not even for the input. This is an image of the event listeners for the element:

[image]

I have tried the same line on jsFiddle and there is not such behavior so I am confused, any advices?

Comment: You must have some other Javascript scripts running...

Comment: `<input type="image"...` has the same behavior and `<input type="submit"...`, so unless you do some javascript that prevents default behavior for that form, it will be submitted to the url specified in the `action` attribute of the `<form>` tag or to same page, if none.

Comment: @i-- That's the problem. I have add `javascript: return false;` to the `onClick()` event and it removes the default behavior